# How can I programatically modify a FrameLayout's layout_weight?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-framelayout

I am trying to achieve a dynamic layout where there are 2 fragments (1 takes up the top 80% of the screen, and the other takes up the bottom 20% of the screen), and I want to be able to dynamically hide the bottom fragment and stretch the top fragment to fill the screen.

If there's an alternative way of doing it I'd like to know, but for now I only know of 1 way to do it. So I have 2 FrameLayouts and I am trying to set the layout_weight of the top FrameLayout (main_container) to 5.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.jobby.jobbydriver.activity.main"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/ColorBG"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_container"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my code,

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_container);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) frameLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.weight = 5.0f; // "weight" is red, (Cannot resolve symbol 'weight')
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

At the 2nd line from the bottom, params.weight is showing up in red, so weight is not a value of params here. This works for LinearLayout, but not FrameLayout, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The `FrameLayout` is inside a `LinearLayout`, so it has `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, not `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`. You will find the `weight` field in the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: @MikeM., your comment is almost an answer, and a correct one. Don't you want to change it to an answer?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I was actually gonna try to find a duplicate, but I'm busy in a chat at the moment. If you want, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: @MikeM., I'll check for a duplicate first

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get any view/viewgroups layout params it will give its parent's layout param.

By considering this you will get a `LenearLayout.LayoutParams` not `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.

So, try this:

```
    FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_container);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) frameLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.weight = 5.0f;
    frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**NB:** you already set weightsum 5. So, also consider to change other view weight.

Comment: Nice, this way is much better than the top answer in the duplicate post because this way only requires me to set the weight. And I'll consider whether it's better to change the other view's visibility or change its weight or both.